# How to add custom styles to a link in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

Am using the admin LTE and would like to customize the sidebar as part of my layout

```
Am customizing a link in yii2 by adding an extra style.
I have tried:
<li>
<?= Html::a('<span> Site </span>',['/site/index'],['class'=>'fa fa- calendar'],
  ['options'=>['template'=>'<small class="label pull-right bg-red">3</small>',
        ]]) ?>

    </li>
```

The final result should be:

```
<li>
      <a href="pages/calendar.html">
            <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i> <span>Calendar</span>
            <small class="label pull-right bg-red">3</small>
          </a>
 </li>
```

The problem is that the part:

```
small class="label pull-right bg-red">3</small>
does not get displayed
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this way

```
<li>
 <?= Html::a('<span> Site </span><small class="label pull-right bg-red">3</small>',
    ['/site/index'],
    ['class'=>'fa fa- calendar'],
 ]) ?>
</li>
```